# Gmapping stops updating map

Tags: ros, navigation, gmapping, vrep, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

after finally getting deeper into ROS and understanding most of the things which are necessary for using the Gmapping-SLAM ( basics like tf, odom etc ) im now at the point of testing the whole thing. There is the Problem that Gmapping stops updating the map after serval scans. But first of all i want to give you a short overview:

**What i want to do:** Im trying to use a simulated 2D-Scanner in VREP as source for Gmapping.

**Systemconfig:** I use Groovy on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a old IBM X41 Laptop (1.5Ghz Centrino SinglecoreCPU)

**Progress:**

1. I transfered the /scan and /odom-Topic from VREP to ROS.
2. I wrote some code (odom_baselink_tf.py) for tf of /base_link to /odom:

> ```
> def metadata_odom(data):
>     global p, q, info
>     info = data
>     p = data.pose.pose.position
>     q = data.pose.pose.orientation
>     rospy.loginfo(Received odom)
> ...
> broadcaster.sendTransform(
>   (p.x, p.y, 0), 
>   (q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w),
>   rosnow,
>   base_lin,
>   odom
>   )
> ```

3 . I use a static tf transform between base_link and LaserScanner_Frame: `rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link LaserScanner_Frame 100`

This results in the following tf-tree:
[image: image description]

I use Gmapping with the following Settings:

```
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="2"/>  <!--2-->
    <param name="maxUrange" value="5.5"/> 
    <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kernelSize" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
    <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
    <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
    <param name="srr" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="srt" value="0.02"/><!--1.0-->
    <param name="str" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="stt" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="0.1"/>     
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.1"/>  
    <param name="temporalUpdate" value="-1.0"/> 
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="particles" value="50"/>  <!--80-->
    <param name="xmin" value="-50.0"/>
    <param name="ymin" value="-50.0"/>
    <param name="xmax" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="ymax" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.03"/>
    <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
    <param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
```

But if i use these settings, there is the problem that Gmapping stops updating the map after serval scans. If i look at the SLAM-Debug-Messages there are serval odd messages:

```
update frame 7
update ld=0.0495583 ad=0.179583
Laser Pose= 13.7771 3.96148 -0.695156
m_count 7
[DEBUG] [1403512083.321312113]: TF operating on not fully resolved frame id base_link, resolving using local prefix 
[DEBUG] [1403512083.321624443]: TF operating on not fully resolved frame id odom, resolving using local prefix 
Average Scan Matching Score=164.656
neff= 49.8545
Registering Scans:Done
[DEBUG] [1403512083.931338640]: scan processed
[DEBUG] [1403512083.933940439]: new best pose: 13.752 3.943 -0.644
[DEBUG] [1403512083.935263651]: odom pose: 13.777 3.961 -0.695
[DEBUG] [1403512083.936265942]: correction: -0.025 -0.018 0.051
[DEBUG] [1403512083.937573997]: Trajectory tree:
[DEBUG] [1403512083.938640263]:   13.752 3.943 -0.644
[DEBUG] [1403512084.006696687]:   13.513 4.059 -0.069
[DEBUG] [1403512084.010663464]: Reading is NULL
[DEBUG] [1403512085.983524674]: TF operating on not fully resolved frame id base_link, resolving using local prefix 
[DEBUG] [1403512085.985853674]: TF operating on not fully resolved frame id odom, resolving using local prefix 
[DEBUG] [1403512087.105476077]: Updated the map
[DEBUG] [1403512087.117026498]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Added message in frame /LaserScanner_Frame at time 1403512075.593, count now 1
[DEBUG] [1403512087.118606658]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Discarding Message, in frame /LaserScanner_Frame, Out of the back of Cache Time(stamp: 1403512072.685 + cache_length: 10.000 < latest_transform_time 1403512085.969.  Message Count now: 1
[DEBUG] [1403512087.120816298]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Added message in frame /LaserScanner_Frame at time 1403512078.106, count now 1
[DEBUG] [1403512087.121834794]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Message ready in frame /LaserScanner_Frame at time 1403512080.746, count now 1
[DEBUG] [1403512087.122950160]: TF operating on not fully resolved frame id odom, resolving using local prefix 
[DEBUG] [1403512087.126866647]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Added message in frame /LaserScanner_Frame at time 1403512080.746, count now 1
[DEBUG] [1403512087.128059466]: Time jumped forward by [5.379792] for timer of period [0.010000], resetting timer (current=1403512087.128015, next_expected=1403512081.748223)
```

The messages show the last Map-Update (#7). There are also some "`TF operating on not fully resolved frame id` "-Messages which i dont understand, because i got all transformations in my tf tree. These messages occur as i start gmapping. What should i do against them? I think they are resulting in my problem.
Or maybe the processingpower of my old laptop is the problem? Top says its always 100%.

Does someone got a idea whats wrong with my setup? Any additional graphics needed to understand the whole thing?

EDIT:
Okey, is it right that the tf-Rate of my `/odom_baselink_tf.py` script needs to be higher, as the buffer is about 10s and the rate of the script is below 1Hz ? Could i reduce slam-tf-rates, as i cant increase the odom publish-rate of the VREP-Simulator ? Or i am complety wrong?
Additionally i switched over to a x200 Laptop with a Core2duo. This way i got a publish rate of about 3 Hz for odom via VREP.

EDIT2:
I found the `transform_publish_period`-Gmapping-parameter and set it to 10Hz. Additionally i changed my pythonscript to publish tf at 10Hz. Every tf in my tree uses now 10Hz for publishing. But the map still dont update.

Cheers
Julian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174585/gmapping-stops-updating-map/) by [julled](https://answers.ros.org/users/17776/julled/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-25**:
Are you maybe mixing times from different sources? Is there a /clock topic or/and maybe a simulation time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fully resolved frame id warnings are not problematic. It's basically `base_link` vs. `/base_link`, where if you just send `base_link` it's gonna make it to be `/base_link`. This is usually what you want.

What you should look at is the "Out of the back of Cache Time(stamp: 1403512072.685 + cache_length: 10.000 " and " Time jumped forward by [5.379792] for timer of period ". This seems like something is wrong with the messages you are sending. All messages should be arriving continuously with a nicely increasing timestamp and laser and tf should fit together. It seems that something in your data doesn't.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [julled](https://answers.ros.org/users/17776/julled/) on 2014-06-24**:
Hey domhege, thank you for your answer! You can see a new EDIT at the question.

gruß aus Berlin

**Comment by [andreas.gerken](https://answers.ros.org/users/19000/andreas.gerken/) on 2014-06-25**:
Hi julled,

sorry for the off-topic but i think we try to do pretty much the same system. Could you send me a mail to andreas.gerken (at) thi.de so we can join powers?

Thanks Andreas

Gruß aus Ingolstadt :)